# Регулярные выражения с++ и boost::regex

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, boost

Помогите пожалуйста с рег. выражением. 
Как сделать так чтобы вот это выражение ([^a-zA]*) принимало только числа и запятую? 
Например assign = "var=345.256"

```
std::string assign; 
boost::regex regex("([a-zA-Z0-9]*)=([^a-zA]*)"); 
boost::cmatch result; 
std::string identifier; 
double value; 
if (boost::regex_match(assign.c_str(), result, regex)) 
{ 
    identifier = std::string(result[1].first, result[1].second); 
    value = boost::lexical_cast<double>(std::string(result[2].first,result[2].second)); 
}
```

Comment: Уточните что вы хотите сделать. Мне не понятно как выражение *"принимало только числа и запятую"* соотносится с примером *"assign = "var=345.256""*

Comment: Если ответ Вам подходит, то отметьте его галочкой(рядом с ответом). Не нужно оставлять благодарность в качестве ответа — для этого есть комментарии.

Comment: Как сделать чтобы вот это число 779 содержало только цифры 1 и 4? Например, 311. Надо бы как-то получше формулировать, хотя в целом вопрос понятен.. Если перечитать его после кода.

Answer (score 1):

Нужное Вам регулярное выражение может выглядеть так:
`"(\\w+)=([+-]?(\\d*[.,])?\\d*)"`, или так `R"xx((\w+)=([+-]?(\d*[.,])?\d*))xx"`.